# How to add text on pdf using PDFJam

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I am using PDF Jam for manipulating pdf. I need to add a text line at the bottom of generated file. I tried it but not able to made it.
Can anybody guide me how to do it?

I did in my php code as

```
$command = '-----------------';
exec($command);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, PDFJAM is for manipulating pds. It is a small collection of shell scripts which provide a simple interface to much of the functionality of the excellent pdf pages. See the  Ubuntu Manual

[pdfjam - A shell script for manipulating PDF files](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/pdfjam.1.html)

You should create your sheet as your doing (5x6) and create a separate sheet of minimal page size with required information than merge both the file into one.

Else in first step create your sheet and use **[pdflib](http://www.pdflib.com/)** to add text as second step. It very good tool. I hope its a good solution of your problem.

Comment: this all I know. please see my question first

Comment: can you give us little description of you problem i.e. what exactly you are doing?

Comment: I have a sheet, which can have 30 cards(visiting cards). So I print them 6card per rows. So total rows are 5 on that page. I am adding card pdfs usinf PDFJam. So you can say I am adding 30 pdf file to 1 file so that I can print them in once. Now I need to add 1 line information about sheet in header or footer, wherever.

Comment: In my opinion, you would need to write a shell script, because pdfjam doesn't provides such functionality.

Comment: else you can do one more thing as you are having 30 cards in a sheet means 5x6 as size just make it as 6x6 and in last row, create apdf with required information than add it using pdfjam. but it will increase your paper size.

Comment: for the mean while I can do that but it increase the paper size. Its a solution but not the best solution

Comment: I having something in my mind so i am posting it as answer..might be helpful for you

Comment: it can work but pdfjam divide papersize into rows equally. If i create a new pdf and combile that with original one than pdfjam will divide the paper size in 2 rows equally (50-50%).

Comment: thanks for your concern. I tried it with pdflib. It works. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I love pdftk and so wanted to find a solution using that.  The following worked for me.

```
pdfjam --preamble '\usepackage{fancyhdr} \topmargin 85pt \oddsidemargin 140pt \cfoot{\thepage}'  --pagecommand '\thispagestyle{plain}' --landscape  --nup 2x1  --frame false --clip true --trim ".5in 0.5in 0.5in .65in" --delta '-0.25in 0' tmp.pdf
```

I cribbed it from: [Page Numbering with the "{page} of {pages}"](https://erny-rev.blogspot.com/2017/05/fast-pdf-scaling-with-page-numbering.html), removing the "of pages" part.

Command converts pdf to 2x1, trims margins, and crops.  Output is landscape.

\topmargin and \oddsidemargin seem to tell pdflatex where to put the numbers.